# asp:RequiredFieldValidator positioning and visibility with scrolling down for Save button

Tags: asp.net

I've too many fields in ASP.NET webform (mostly asp:dropdownlist, asp:TextBox, etc). After filling the data, and at the bottom of screen, there is a save button. When I click on Save button (ASP.NET control asp:Button), how do I take the control to required fields missed the input (red message is showing, however, users may not know to scroll-up and fill the necessary info). Is there any way I focus on the required field without submitting the page to code-behind? Help is appreciated.

Issue is with losing the visibility of required fields, users are hiting save button again and again without success (they may not know to scroll-up and check any required fields in red).

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label><b>State</b></label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStates" class="form-control m-b" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" DataTextField="Descr" DataValueField="Value" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
        <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Choose State" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqStates" runat="server" InitialValue="" ControlToValidate="ddlStates" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="State selection is required." />
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label><b>Zip Code</b></label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-control input-sm" ID="txtZipCode" MaxLength="2000" /><br />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqZipCode" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtZipCode" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The Zip Code is required." />
</div>
```

After so many fields like this, I have the button at the end when I scroll down there is no way users to know that there are required field at top of the screen.

After hitting Save, the control should be taken back to required fields. Or any sort of ideas to handle at the browser level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following script. It sets the focus to the Control that is invalid. You may need to tweak it to your needs. You can also use this to add an extra CSS Class for invalid elements.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ValidatorUpdateIsValid = function () {
            Page_IsValid = AllValidatorsValid(Page_Validators);

            for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
                inputControl = document.getElementById(Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate);
                if (null != inputControl && !Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
                    inputControl.focus();
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I simply added SetFocusOnError="true" for RequiredFieldValidator and it helped me. Your suggestion is valuable, and I can implement in other pages. I appreciate it.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot that one... stupid... I use the above code to add an error class to the control to make it red, so I modified it to use `focus()` and did not think about the simplest solution.